# What is focusStyle used for inside UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

What is `focusStyle` used for inside `UITableViewCell` and how do one go about customising it?  I tried setting the focusStyle to Custom and implementing `didUpdateFocus(in:with:)` as suggested in the Apple Documentation, but the method was never called and there was no visual clue as to what focusStyle does.

The documentation states that focusStyle is used to set the appearance of the cell when focused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to realize what focus is. Focus is used to control apps on `tvOS`, and can be also used in Catalyst and other types of keyboard navigation (e.g. on iPad).

Start by reading [Working with the apple TV Remote](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/WorkingwiththeAppleTVRemote.html). Then note that the base interface is declared on `UIView` (`UIFocusItem` protocol).

`UITableView` and `UITableViewCell` just have some additional API that you can use to update your cells when they are focused, similar to `setHighlighted(_:animated:)` and `setSelected(_:animated:)`.

Comment: FYI - this answer is out of date since full focus APIs have been part of iOS since iOS 14.

Comment: @HangarRash huh? Could you provide more information? How do you focus a cell on iOS?

Comment: The easiest way is to point you to Apple's sample app: [Navigating an App’s User Interface Using a Keyboard](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uikeycommand/navigating_an_app_s_user_interface_using_a_keyboard). Also see [Focus-based navigation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/focus-based_navigation).

Comment: Note that the sample app and that documentation don't really help answer the original question. But as of iOS 14, overriding `didUpdateFocus` in a UITableView or UITableViewCell subclass does result in it being called giving a chance to update the focus effect in some way. The WWDC video linked in the sample app does mention that it is possible.

Comment: @HangarRash Oh, right, iOS needs that now because of Catalyst. However, the last paragraph actually explains that it's just another way to update UI. I will expand the answer a bit.